# PHP: How to format datetime to use if/else for CSS

Tags: php, html, css, datetime

Title probably doesn't make much sense; I'm a PHP amateur.

I'm attempting to create a custom member tag for my forum that will display "X Years of Experience" but with different colors for each individual year such as red for under 6 months, blue for year one, yellow for year two, and so forth.

This is the code I'm currently using:

```
<div class="ipsType_center memExperience" data-ipstooltip="">
{{$joinDate = $comment->author()->get_joined(); $currentDate = new \DateTime(); $interval = $joinDate->diff($currentDate); $experience = \IPS\DateTime::formatInterval($interval, 1);}}
    <li class="ipsResponsive_hidePhone memCustomFields">{$experience} {lang="memberexperience_experience"}</li>
```

I was able to find a working sample for getting the date difference and it works fine. Now, I just need to figure out how to turn $experience into a value that I can use with CSS.

I also found code that allows you to format a variable into hours for comparison. This is that code:

```
<?php 
 $hour = $experience->format('H');
 if ($hour < 12) {
   echo "Morning";
 } else {
   echo "Afternoon or evening";
 }
?>
```

This doesn't work for me because my output is always X Days, X Months, or X Years. There's always a number associated but it could be days, months, of years.

What I'm trying to do is something like...

```
{{if $experience < 6 Months}}
Make Text Red
{{elseif $experience > 1 Year}}
Make Text Blue
{{elseif $experience > 2 Years}}
Make Text Yellow
...
```

I feel like a switch might be the better option here but again, I'm not real sure how to make sure that $experience is converted to days, months, years.

Comment: Show us the output of `var_dump($experience);`

Comment: Is `$joinDate` a `DateTime` object or a string?

Comment: if you can convert the $experience into number of days, you can create that IF statement easier, then try to create a class that will handle the color changing font.

Comment: @Nick It's a string. $joinDate is the user's registration date in MM/DD/YYYY format.

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie Can't do that, unfortunately. I'm not doing this locally.

Comment: You'll need to convert it into a `DateTime` object using [`date_create_from_format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) then to use `->diff` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$joinDate` is not already a datetime, then convert it to one:

`$joinDatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $joinDate);`

Do your diff on the two datetime objects:

`$interval = $joinDatetime->diff($currentDate);`

Then, you need to convert the difference into months:

`$months = $interval->m + ($interval->y * 12);`

Assign a class to a variable, and echo out that variable in your html. For example:

```
$class = 'default';

if ($months < 6) {
    $class = 'red';
} elseif ($months > 12) {
    $class = 'blue'; 
} elseif ($months > 24) {
    $class = 'yellow';
}
```

Then in your html, do something like this:

```
<li class="ipsResponsive_hidePhone memCustomFields {$class}">{$experience}{lang="memberexperience_experience"}</li>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work exactly as described but you got me started in the right direction and I've finally got it working. Huge thanks!

Not that this helps anyone per se because this is for forum software, I might as well post my results anyway just to show my work and some thanks to you for the assistance. Since it'd be too big for a comment, here's a link to PasteBin showing everything but the final eight years or so. It's a little clunky but it works. https://pastebin.com/0A9kfWEn

Comment: Cool, nice work. If it helped please upvote my answer :)